# Mysql Database Table Construction depending on a base

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I've been developing an app that will contain Prices, Product Types and Users.
I was just wondering if how are you going to handle or create a database table of Prices for the User.

For Example :

I have several users and each user is on different location. I also have a base price basis that will provide the users prices, but I every Product changes its price depending on its location. Is there any way of me not duplicating the Products? Because I've created a separate table that will be for each users Product and it consumes too much memory on the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a table of Users with Primary Key, A table of Products with Primary Key. Then A Third table with prices and the Primary Key's of the other two tables.